# Check if a given linked list is palindrome

Tags: python, linked-list, palindrome

I am solving interview questions from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/palindrome-list/).

> Problem :Given a singly linked list, determine if its a palindrome. Return 1 or 0 denoting if its a palindrome or not, respectively.
>
> Notes:Expected solution is linear in time and constant in space.
> For example,
> List 1-->2-->1 is a palindrome.
> List 1-->2-->3 is not a palindrome.

How can this solution be improved ?

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Solution:
    def __init__(self,seq):
        """prepends item of lists into linked list"""
        self.head = None
        for item in seq:
            node = ListNode(item)
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node
              
    
    def list_palin(self):
        """ Returns 1 if linked list is palindrome else 0"""
        node = self.head
        fast = node
        prev = None
        ispal = True

        # prev approaches to middle of list till fast reaches end or None 
        while fast and fast.next: 
            fast = fast.next.next
            temp = node.next   #reverse elemets of first half of list
            node.next = prev
            prev = node
            node = temp

        if fast:  # in case of odd num elements
            tail = node.next
        else:    # in case of even num elements
            tail = node
      
        
        while prev and ispal:
            # compare reverse element and next half elements          
            if prev.val == tail.val:
                tail = tail.next
                prev = prev.next
                ispal = True
            else:
                ispal = False
                break
      
        if ispal :
            return 1
        else :
            return 0
# Test Cases
listpal_1 = Solution([7, 8, 6 ,  3 , 7 ,3 , 6, 8, 7])
assert listpal_1.list_palin()
listpal_2 = Solution([6 , 3 , 7, 3, 6])
assert listpal_2.list_palin()
listpal_3 = Solution([3, 7 ,3 ])
assert listpal_3.list_palin()
listpal_4 = Solution([1])
assert listpal_4.list_palin()
```

Comment: is the input just a list....do you need to convert it to a ListNode?

Comment: @depperm the inputs are not provided by the site, only the function list_palin is open for writing the code, rest all is inbuilt in the site. I didn't find any better way to take inputs by  self.

Comment: Is this linear in space?  It seems to be building a reversed copy of the linked list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### More tests

Having a test suite is nice.
It would be even nicer to make it more comprehensive by adding:

- edge cases (empty list for instance)
- inputs with an even number of elements
- negative test cases : input is not a palindrome.

Here is a suggestion, I took this chance to remove the duplicated logic by extracting the data into a proper data structure:

```
# Test Cases
tests = [
    ([], True),
    ([1], True),
    ([1, 1], True),
    ([1, 2], False),
    ([3, 7, 3], True),
    ([3, 7, 4], False),
    ([6, 3, 7, 3, 6], True),
    ([7, 8, 6, 3, 7, 3, 6, 8, 7], True),
    ([7, 8, 6, 3, 7, 4, 6, 8, 7], False),
]
for inp, expected in tests:
    res = Solution(inp).list_palin()
    if res != expected:
        print("%s: %d != %d" % (inp, res, expected))
```

#### Using the boolean type

The bool type is expected for this type of situation (even if in Python, booleans are also integers equal to 0 or 1).

Many things can be simplified then:

```
    if ispal :
        return 1
    else :
        return 0
```

becomes:

```
    return ispal
```

Also, you can return False directly in the `else` block of the `while` loop.
Then, it becomes more obvious that you never assign `False` to `ispal`. You can get rid of it and all the logic around it.

```
def list_palin(self):
    """ Check if linked list is palindrome and return True/False."""
    node = self.head
    fast = node
    prev = None

    # prev approaches to middle of list till fast reaches end or None 
    while fast and fast.next:
        fast = fast.next.next
        temp = node.next   #reverse elemets of first half of list
        node.next = prev
        prev = node
        node = temp

    if fast:  # in case of odd num elements
        tail = node.next
    else:    # in case of even num elements
        tail = node

    while prev:
        # compare reverse element and next half elements          
        if prev.val == tail.val:
            tail = tail.next
            prev = prev.next
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

#### Do we need that much code?

Depending on what you are trying to achieve personally, you may or may not need to re-implement a linked list.

Also, having a class named `Solution` seems a bit awkward here.

#### Function/method to compare list

The final block of the function compares 2 lists. It may be worth moving this to a function on its own.

Even better, you could define an `__eq__` method in the `ListNode` class:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, ListNode) and self.val == other.val and self.next == other.next
```

and then just write:

```
    if fast:  # in case of odd num elements
        tail = node.next
    else:    # in case of even num elements
        tail = node

    return prev == tail
```

Comment: Note that returning a `bool` fails to conform to the spec here.

Comment: @Schism Yeah, well, not all interview questions are created equal, time for the old "I wuold have requested a boolean" to score bonus points in your interview.